# Blockdata Errors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a /blockdata command that I'm using the latest snapshot as a test, but something very confusing is happening. By standards, this command:

```
blockdata ~ ~1 ~ {Text1: "{ text:\"[Say Hi]\", \"color\":\"dark_blue\",\"clickEvent\":\"{ action:run_command, value:\"/say hi\" }\"}"}
```

Should work. However, any time I try to use a blockdata command, I get:

```
[00:00:00] An unknown error occurred while attempting to perform this command
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're playing 1.9, you must use proper JSON syntax, in that **all** key names and string values must be surrounded in quotes. You are missing quotes for the `text` key, the `action` key/value, and the `value` key. You also have a stray quotation marks surrounding the brackets for `clickEvent`.

Fixed command:

```
/blockdata ~ ~1 ~ {Text1:"{\"text\":\"[Say Hi]\",\"color\":\"dark_blue\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/say hi\"}}"}
```